# Cambiar Boton de Formulario de Disable a Enable Python- Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, chrome

Buenas Tengo la siguiente duda, me encuentra realizando un proyecto de automatización, sin embargo mi problema empieza al momento de resolver un recaptcha a través de la api de anticaptcha, esta me otorga la solución del mismo sin embargo no es posible darle continuar debido a que el botón que se encarga de dicha función se encuentra desactivado, modificando el código de manera manual es posible eliminar el problema. Mi pregunta ¿ Es posible cambiar dicho estado Disable a Enable haciendo uso de python- Selenium?
[image: Muestra del Código del Botón]

He estado haciendo uso de execute_script con las diferentes formas de hallar el boton(Xpath,id,classname) todo esto sin resultado Alguno

Comment: Con selenium es como si tu estuvieras navegando, por lo que tu tendrás que acceder a la consola y cambiar la propiedad

Comment: No me parece muy necesario fijate con el siguiente codigo es posible cambiar el estilo css de la pagina en la cual se le aplica selenium driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('lga').style.display = 'none';"). pero no tengo idea de como cambiar el estado de ese boton a traves de ese codigo

Comment: desconozco selenium totalmente, lo que te dije fue algo general (característica de selenium). El código js sería `document.getElementById("id_del_boton").disable = true;` o `false` según lo que quieras.

Comment: Vale Compañero, intento con este codigo y todo funcional driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('continue').removeAttribute('disabled');")  . Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Logre hacer que el botón cambiara de estado con el siguiente código:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('continue').removeAttribute('disabled');)
```

Aquí se identifica al botón y se elimina su atributo `disabled` de esta forma ya se tiene habilitado al botón.